# J2ME - MIDP. Get error (40-Error in HTTP operation) with POST request to server

Tags: java-me, nokia, midp

i try run code copied from this tutorial
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Http_POST_request_in_Java_ME

But when i run it i get Exception in source code line

```
 dis = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());


java.io.IOException: 40-Error in HTTP operation
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.checkForException(+51)
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.readResponseMessage_wap(+38)
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect_wap(+649)
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(+107)
    at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol$PrivateOutputStream.flush(+39)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
    at com.orionsource.onlinenards.api.API.sendPostRequest(API.java:221)
    at com.orionsource.onlinenards.api.API.helloApiWithParams(API.java:259)
    at com.orionsource.onlinenards.OnLineNards.startApp(OnLineNards.java:33)
    at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(+7)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: it's possible that connection isn't correct. can you print hc.gerResponseCode() ??

Comment: No,i can't. Now this exception i get when try getResponseCode() call.

Comment: I wonder if 40- refers to the 40x http codes. The example you linked uses "http://localhost" as the server. Are you running a local server or did you change the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample code.It will help u.

```
HttpConnection hc=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
DataInputStream dis = fc.openDataInputStream();
```